# How to show x power 2 (sup) in button element

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm creating a standard calculator in a reactjs projects. There is a button which calculates x power 2 for that i'm using html element `<sup>` to do that but that is not working

`<Button name = "x<sup>2</sup>" clickHandler = {this.buttonClickHandler} />`

Button element is created from this code:

```
<button onClick = {this.buttonClickHandler}>{this.props.name}</button>
```

I want to show text like this x<sup>2</sup>[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) like this:

```html
<button onClick={this.buttonClickHandler} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.name}} />
```

--- Original post below, because the author didn't specified the "x²" was coming from React ---

Buttons doesn't work like inputs. They are regular tags (that don't close themselves), and their contents is between the opening and the closing tag.

You don't want `<button name="THE CONTENT" />`.

You want `<button>THE CONTENT</button>`

So in your case, you can just do this:

```html
<button clickHandler = {this.buttonClickHandler}>x<sup>2</sup></button>
```

Comment: yes.. doing it in this way only but it is not working.. <button onClick = {this.buttonClickHandler}>{this.props.name}</button>

Comment: @AshokGadri And why is it not working? Can you show examples? Errors? Screenshots? Edit your post and show what you've tried and what are the results.

Comment: @AshokGadri Edit **YOUR OWN** post, not mine. Also add examples of your own code.

Comment: Added the image and the code.